# Node.JS request cookies cached

Tags: node.js, express, caching, cookies

i had an Node.js function that update a cookie when the server is called on an endpoint with a GET call.The browser calls this endpoint and pass this cookie that is already set, when the api is called, it print the cookie value and then update the cookie with a new value. The value printed of the cookie is always the same. I checked the cookie values in the browser and it seems to be correctly update, when i debug the node.js incoming request it has the first value of the cookie like the request has been cached and never changes. The new value assigned to the cookie is correctly updated. This is a JSON cors call performed with XMLHttpRequest on the client side. Anyone has any advice? i set 'cache-control':'private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate', 'Expires':'0','Pragma':'no-cache' as header in both client request and server response but this does not work. Instead if i add a queryparams to the request address contains for example a timestamp or a date in ISOString it works!

Comment: Can you share your code which is updating cookie?

Comment: unfortunately for corporate policy I can't, but i provide you an example of it
router.get('/myaction',function(req,res,next) {
    var newCheck = new Date().toISOString();
    console.log("myCheck " + req.cookies.check);
    res.clearCookie("check" , { path: cookiePath, httpOnly: cookieFlags.httpOnly, secure: cookieFlags.secure, domain:cookieFlags.domain});
    res.cookie("check" , newCheck, { path: cookiePath, httpOnly: cookieFlags.httpOnly, secure: cookieFlags.secure, domain:cookieFlags.domain});
    var myResponse = {
        result : 'success'
    };
    res.json(myResponse);
});

Comment: My use case requires this function to be called very frequently, for example every 2 - 5 seconds.
i'm doing some tests using lower frequency like 30 minutes and with this frequency the cookie is correctly retrieved and updated